Hide WooCommerce product attributes with empty values from a custom shortcode
I used the code below to display a certain amount of attributes within a Custom Tab by using a shortcode. This works fine but not all products carry the same specs. How can I hide the lines that contain no data?
I entered this code:
// Display grouped attributes Gewicht en Omvang
function get_product_attributes_gewicht_shortcode( $atts ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'id'    => get_the_ID(),
), $atts, 'display-attributes-gewicht' ) );

global $product;

if ( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $id );
}
if ( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
    $gewicht = $product->get_attribute( 'Gewicht (gram)' );
    $hoogte = $product->get_attribute( 'Hoogte (mm)');
    $lengte = $product->get_attribute( 'Lengte (mm)');
    $breedte = $product->get_attribute( 'Breedte (mm)');
    return '<div class="divTableAtt LichtBlauweRegels">' .
                '<div class="divTableAttBody">' .
                    '<div class="divTableAttRow">' .
                        '<div class="divTableAttCell">Gewicht (gram)</div>' .
                        '<div class="divTableAttCell">' . $gewicht . '</div>' .
                    '</div>' .
                    '<div class="divTableAttRow">' .
                        '<div class="divTableAttCell">Hoogte (mm)</div>' .
                        '<div class="divTableAttCell">' . $hoogte . '</div>' .
                    '</div>' .
                    '<div class="divTableAttRow">' .
                        '<div class="divTableAttCell">Lengte (mm)</div>' .
                        '<div class="divTableAttCell">' . $lengte . '</div>' .
                    '</div>' .
                    '<div class="divTableAttRow">' .
                        '<div class="divTableAttCell">Breedte (mm)</div>' .
                        '<div class="divTableAttCell">' . $breedte . '</div>' .
                    '</div>' .
                '</div>' .
            '</div>';
}
}
add_shortcode( 'display-attributes-gewicht', 'get_product_attributes_gewicht_shortcode' );`

I want to hide the  if the attirube in that row is empty.
I tried to use and if statement around that row, but it doesn't work.
if (isset($breedte)){
return '<div class="divTableAttRow">' .
'<div class="divTableAttCell">Breedte (mm)</div>' .
'<div class="divTableAttCell">' . $breedte . '</div>' .
'</div>';
}

I did close the line before with a ;
and started the line after with a new 'return' statement.
The results are that the entire result of other functions are shown and not only this set as it is suposed to.
I am still learning this and figuring out how to get it to work.

@DarkBee sorry my bad. I am using 2 parts of code in one example. I changed the code I added to reflect what I did (but now properly)

I'm guessing $product->get_attribute( 'Breedte (mm)') returns an empty string which isset doesn't account for. Related: isset() and empty() - what to use

Just assemble the desired output in a string variable first, then you can use if conditions to add parts to it for non-empty attributes. Return that string value at the very end.

Breedte does have a value set and is displayed and is only used for an example. I got this [productpage] (https://shop.r-go-tools.com/alle-producten/r-go-numpad-break-zwart-draadloos) and if you scroll down to the product tab "Specificaties" and the nested tab called "Algemeen" you will see 2 empty values: 'Layout toetsenbord' and 'Multimediatoetsen'.
I want to hide those 2 lines for example. The table is generated exactly the way as the code above.
Do I need to rewrite the code? Or can I easy adjust this one to do what I want it to do.
Can you give me an example please?

As already pointed out an empty string does not mean a variable isn't set. Please read the linked question/answers - demo. Furthermore, please verify the actual value of $breedte - var_dump($breedte)

I read the page and used the following code:
  if (isset($layoutkb)){
    if (strlen($layoutkb) > 0) {
      return '<div class="divTableAttRow">' .
       '<div class="divTableAttCell">Lay-out toetsenbord</div>' .
       '<div class="divTableAttCell">' . $layoutkb . 
'</div>' .
     '</div>';
     } 
  }

But now the tab is filled with other attributes which are not in this script.
Does it have anything to do with having 3 return commands after eachother?

"Does it have anything to do with having 3 return commands after eachother?" - yes, because you can only return out of a function/method once. Hence my advice, that you assemble the desired content in a string variable first, and then return that, once, at the very end.

I am to new at this apparantly... I will dive back in my books and see how to do this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Try the following revised shortcode that will display only the defined product attributes:
// Display grouped attributes Gewicht en Omvang
add_shortcode( 'display-product-attributes', 'shortcode_display_product_attributes' );
function shortcode_display_product_attributes( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id'    => get_the_ID(),
    ), $atts, 'display-product-attributes' ) );

    global $product;

    if ( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $id );
    }

    if ( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
        $gewicht = $product->get_attribute('Gewicht (gram)');
        $hoogte  = $product->get_attribute('Hoogte (mm)');
        $lengte  = $product->get_attribute('Lengte (mm)');
        $breedte = $product->get_attribute('Breedte (mm)');

        if ( $gewicht || $hoogte || $lengte || $breedte ) {
            $output = '<div class="divTableAtt LichtBlauweRegels">
            <div class="divTableAttBody">';

            if ( $gewicht ) {
                $output .= '<div class="divTableAttRow">
                <div class="divTableAttCell">Gewicht (gram)</div>
                <div class="divTableAttCell">' . $gewicht . '</div>
                </div>';
            }

            if ( $hoogte ) {
                $output .= '<div class="divTableAttRow">
                <div class="divTableAttCell">Hoogte (mm)</div>
                <div class="divTableAttCell">' . $hoogte . '</div>
                </div>';
            }

            if ( $lengte ) {
                $output .= '<div class="divTableAttRow">
                <div class="divTableAttCell">Lengte (mm)</div>
                <div class="divTableAttCell">' . $lengte . '</div>
                </div>';
            }

            if ( $breedte ) {
                $output .= '<div class="divTableAttRow">
                <div class="divTableAttCell">Breedte (mm)</div>
                <div class="divTableAttCell">' . $breedte . '</div>
                </div>';
            }

            return $output . '</div></div>';
        }
    }
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

I tried the code and it works exactly how I want. I forgot about the .= to combine it. Thanks for the help and explanations everyone. I upvoted the answer, but am not high enough on reputation yet.

thanks, didn't know that was also needed.
